# Word Templates in Document Library do not open as templates

Tags: word

We have word templates stored in a document library.  We want to be able to open the templates as if they were on a shared drive - where they open as a new document.  Where they are stored now they just open to edit the template directly.  I keep reading to use content types but this doesn't seem from my reading to satisfy the solution 100%.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Office do you have?